# Topologies generated by a metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Hi I am new to mathematical proofs/notation and am working through John Lee's Introduction to Topilogical Manifolds. This is the question and my attempt. This is not homework.

2.4
Suppose $M$ is a set and $d$, $d'$ are two different metrics on $M$. Prove that $d$ and $d'$ generate the same topology iff for every $x\in M$ and every $r>0$, there exist positive numbers $r_1$ and $r_2$ such that $B_{r_1}^{(d')}(x) \subseteq B_r^{(d)}(x)$ and $B_{r_2}^{(d)}(x) \subseteq B_r^{(d')}(x)$.

My attempt so far:

Each generated topology is the collection of all the open subsets in the metric space sense. Assuming both generated topologies are the same:

$\tau = \tau^d = \tau^{d'}$

$\iff$

$\{ A : A \subseteq M,~and~if~x\in A,\exists~B_r^{(d)}=\{y\in M:d(x,y)<r\}\subseteq A\}=$
$\{ A : A \subseteq M,~and~if~x\in A,\exists~B_r^{(d')}=\{y\in M:d'(x,y)<r\}\subseteq A\}$

$\implies$

if $A\in \tau$,and $x\in A$, $\exists~B_{r}^{(d)}(x)\subseteq A$ and $B_{r}^{(d')}(x)\subseteq A$, for some $r>0$.

This is where I am stuck, I don't know how to compare these two subsets of $A$. I know $x$ has to be a member of both but not sure what to do with that. I am new to this sort of thing and appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't want to do this by actually constructing and comparing the sets in the way you did. Just try to deduce it from what was given, and don't think about sets explicitly

Comment: Do you know criteria for checking whether two topologies are the same given bases of each?

Comment: Ideally this should be done without considering bases, as the book hasn't covered them yet. Want to learn to walk before I can run etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the open sets defining a topology $\tau$ on a set $M$ may be defined as a subset $T_{\tau}$ of $\mathfrak{P}(M)$, the power set of $M$ satisfying the open-set axioms. we may write:
$$
\tau_1 \le \tau_2 \Leftarrow \Rightarrow T_{\tau_1} \subseteq T_{\tau_2}
$$
ie $\tau_1$ is weaker (which does not rule out equivalence)  than $\tau_2$ iff every open set of $\tau_1$ is also an open set of $\tau_2$

two topologies are equivalent iff each is weaker than the other. now express this requirement in terms of the open balls. since an arbitrarily small open $\tau_1$ ball around $x$ belongs to $T_{\tau_1}$, then for equivalence this ball must be open also in  $\tau_2$, so it must, in particular contain an open $\tau_2$-ball centered at $x$. and vice versa. this argument shows the necessity of the condition you have stated. can you add a demonstration of its sufficiency?

Comment: Ah so any ball $B_r^{(d)}$ belonging to $(M,d)$ is itself a member of the topology, so as it also an open set wrt to $(M,d')$ then it must contain a ball about each of it's points $B_{r1}^{(d')}$. By demonstrating sufficiency do you mean show the converse statement is true?

Comment: yes. we have shown that equivalence implies the ball condition, so one would like to see that the ball condition guarantees equivalence

Answer (score 0):

for the first direction lets assume that $\tau_{d'}=\tau_d$

given $x\in{M}$ and $r>0$ we get that $B_r^{(d)}(x)\in \tau_{d'}$ then for every $y\in B_r^{(d)}(x)$ there exicet $r_y>0$ such that  $B_{r_y}^{(d')}(x)\subset B_r^{(d)}(x)$ so lets just take one of them as $r_1$.

and it is symmetrical to find $r_2$

for the second direction:
we assume the second condition (in the iff)

take $U\in \tau_d$ then for every $x\in U$ theres $r_x>0$ such that $B_{r_x}^{(d)}(x)\subset  U$ so well get $$\cup_{x\in U}B_{r_x}^{(d)}=U$$

but for every $r_x$ we have $r_{x_1}$ such that $B_{r_{x_1}}^{(d')}(x)\subset B_{r_x}^{(d)}(x)$ so it is easy to see that: $$\cup_{x\in U}B_{r_{x_1}}^{(d)}=U$$ 
then $U$ is in $\tau_{d'}$

so $\tau_d \subset \tau_{d'}$ and to show that $\tau_{d'} \subset \tau_d$ is symmetrical